# Fibonacci Numbers using Dynammic Programming

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, complexity-theory, fibonacci, analysis

I am trying to understand the complexity of Fibonacci series from lecture [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQ5jsbhAv_M). It saying

```
T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)+ theta(1)
```

I can understand till the above part, What I am not understanding is how it becomes as

```
T(n) >= Fn = theta pow n
T(n) >= 2T(n-2)
```

Any explanation would be great.

Comment: 1) Expression `T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)` coincides with an expression for Fibonacci numbers `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)`, and because `T(n)` has an additional non-negative component `theta(1)` it's definitely not less than `F(n)`. Hence, `T(n)>=F(n)`

Comment: 2) `T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + theta(1)` -> `T(n) - T(n-2) = T(n-1) + theta(1) >= T(n-2)` (next Fibonacci number is not less than the previous one) -> `T(n) - T(n-2) >= T(n-2)` -> `T(n) >= 2 * T(n-2)`